# Reading Files from a folder Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

**How can read data in specific interval from a folder in Spark?**

From external source through FTP Flag file and Data files are put to a folder.The Flg file holds info about all the files(like a metadata file).I should process all the files once they available by reading flag file.I am new to spark world.Please suggest the approach.

Ex:-One flg file.
    N no of tar files which contains .csv and xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Spark on a standalone system then corn job should be quite sufficient to schedule your spark job.

If you are running on a cluster, then you have few more options like:
OoZie, Airflow.

Flow would be something like this:

1. Setup cron job for X secs to check the status of Flag file.
2. If flag is set, stop cron job and read/process the contents of the data files.
3. Restart cron job.

You can tune the cron job time, based on below points:

- how large your data is
- how long it takes to process your data
- latency: time between availability of new data and its processing.

If X is too small like 1 sec, it would be better to use sleep in the program and poll at regular intervals.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should schedule a corn job for every 1 sec or X sec to submit by job?

Comment: Yes, if that is the requirement.

Comment: In Spring integration with below code I can scan from a folder for regular interval. Is the same kind of behaviour is possible in Spark.<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples‌​/input" filename-pattern=".*\.xml"> <integration:poller id="poller" > <integration:interval-trigger initial-delay="1000" interval="2000" fixed-rate="true"/> </integration:poller>

Comment: Assuming you are using Scala, you can do this by implementing Scala Future and poll the folder on a regular interval. This would be much similar to a java thread. Be warned this would lead to writing and managing extra code.